# How to find out which software is already installed on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, package-management

I just registered to one hosting company, automatically created a Debian virtual machine and logged as root via PuTTy. However I don't know yet if there any PHP, MySQL or Apache installed.

From my (beginner) point of view let's say Apache should be run as a daemon and listening to a port 80. So I decided that it could be a good idea to list all ports in use: `netstat -lntu` command gave me the short list of 5 lines:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:65000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
udp        0      0 my.ip.add.res:123       0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*
```

OK, looks like nothing listens to 80-th port.

I've tried another approach: looking for a running daemons with `ps aux`. There was a list of about 40-50 lines which I couldn't understand.

Any advises?

Answer (score 2):

On a Debian-based distro you can just run

```
dpkg --get-selections
```

for a list of installed packages. Of course this list does not include anything you manually compiled and installed, but as long as you use `apt-get` (or `aptitude` etc.) to manage software, it'll show in the `dpkg` list.

If you want to check for a certain package, pipe the output through `grep`:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep apache
```

Comment: Also: `dpkg -l 'apache*'` and `apt-cache policy apache2-mpm-worker` etc

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Debian package manager to see if you application is installed. So using your example you can use:

`dpkg -s apache2`

The `-s` option will find out if the package is installed.

Useful resources for this can be found [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-if-package-is-installed-in-linux/) and [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/dpkg-cheat-sheet.php)

Comment: Thank you for the links! Apache is not installed. I made the same thing to `mysql` and `php` words and all of them is not installed. I checked it right?

Comment: You would need to be more specific. If you want a simpler method you can use, as suggested below, dpkg --get-selections | grep apache

Comment: This will not work because there is no package named `apache`. It'll just return "Package 'apache' is not installed and no info is available." Same for MySQL. If you search for `mysql` there is no package with that name. You'd have to know it's called `mysql-client` or `mysql-server` etc.

Comment: Sorry typo on my part. I have corrected my answer and tested it works perfectly fine. I did say in the above comment he would need to be more specific when searching for mysql or php package installs.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `netstat -lnp` as root user, it will show the process names that are listening to the sockets on the server.